# How to fix the problem in the program for decrypting the Caesar cipher?

Tags: c++

```
     #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
 int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
string text = "ІЇЬЩЙКХЧКЬСИЛЧХЙЮІЙБНИКЇИЗБДШЬЗЬЇХКИЇАХЩИІИЖИШИУФЕИШИЄУЩФЖЖИЯЗХЧ";
char arr[32] = { 'А','Б','В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Є', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'І', 'Ї', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ь', 'Ю', 'Я', };
int plus = 1;
for (int b = 1;b < 32;b++) {
    string var =  text;
    for (int i = 0;i < text.length();i++) {
        for (int a = 0;a < 32;a++) {
          if (var[i] == arr[a]) {                 
                if ((a - plus )> 0) {
                    var[i] = arr[a - plus];
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    var[i] = arr[32 +(a - plus)];
                    break;
                }
            }
            ;
        }

    }
    cout << "Ключ =" << plus-1 << "\n \n ";
    for (int c = 0;c < size(var);c++) {
        cout << var[c];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    plus++;
  }
 }
```

A code has been written to deal with the expanding encrypted hedge and the program is working (є the number of texts written in the code)But when I get the decrypted text instead of the letter 'A' there is an incomprehensible character. How to fix the problem?(Ukrainian alphabet )

Comment: Your code is working in this manner https://onlinegdb.com/BkT8WUoVv it is hard to predict.

Comment: This is C++, not C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `a == plus`, you access `arr [32]`.